# Menu control in WPF

Tags: wpf, menu

I want to make **a menu control like the Windows Start menu**. Can anyone give me ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the Ribbon window, like in Office 2oo7 or the Win7 Version of MSPaint or WordPad ?

Comment: i mean like office 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel?  Download and install [Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).

Answer (score 1):

The [Ribbon Feature Walkthrough](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx) is a good starting point. Or just [search SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ribbon+window+%5Bwpf%5D) for Ribbon Window.